# Button "Readmore" appears each time the text is larger than 2 rows length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/qo6ycfpf/
```

In the above code, I collapsed the text so that it is more compact, but the text isn't always the same length. In the demo, second text is short, but the button is appearing "Readmore".

So I want a jQuery/script or a workaround for each time the text height is greater than 50 pixels (or 2 rows), which the "Readmore" button appears.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate each text content `div` using `$.each()` to find it's height and then hide it's corresponding `label`.

**Code snippets:**

```
$("div.text-cmt").each(function () {
    if ($(this).height() < "50") {
        $(this).prev("label").hide();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qo6ycfpf/2/)